# Apache: Invalid command 'RailsEnv', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm using Rails 3 + Apache + Passenger, and I'm trying to deploy to a new server. I'm not too familiar with where RailsEnv comes from and am getting this error when checking the syntax of my apache config.

`Invalid command 'RailsEnv', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Does anyone know what module `RailsEnv` comes from ?

Comment: Do you have passenger module enabled, i.e. in Apache?

Comment: Nope I don't think so. How would I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Install Apache passenger module, following the guides here for your specific environment: http://blog.phusion.nl/2011/03/02/phusion-passenger-3-0-4-released/

Then, enable the module using:

```
sudo a2enmod passenger
```

Finally restart apache.

Comment: I get `ERROR: Module passenger does not exist!`

Comment: just try install passenger `apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger`

Answer (score 0):

For me this was because I copied a linux server config to my mac installation:

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  LoadModule passenger_module .../mod_passenger.so
  PassengerRoot .../locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby .../ruby
</IfModule>
```

Removing the `<IfModule>` tags fixed it for me.  I'm guessing mod_passenger.c doesn't exist on the mac, so then the passenger module is never loaded at all.